# android videoview fullscreen when click button

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-videoview

i want to show fullscreen the video when click a button. And then return old size teh video when run fullscreen!

how can i do that?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/Web"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/screen_background" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="264dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />
```

Comment: Why you use webview?And where your button code?

Comment: dont care webview... i show html code in webview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be declare   videoview as below  in relativelayout, I think, your problem will be resolve.

```
<VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
```

Set theme of that activity... as

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```